# How to listen for QQuickItem childItem adding

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've created c++ class with QML attached properties to use it in qml.

Now I want to add attached property to one `QQuickItem` object and propagate this attached property for all `QQuickItem` child items (those which returned by `QQuickItem::childItems()` not by `QObject::children()`). I can easily iterate over existing `QQuickItem` child items and add attached properties to them, however I can't find out how to listen for added/removed child items for certain `QQuickItem`. No signals, no events only overriding `QQuickItem::itemChange()` method.

How can I listen for adding/removing `QQuickItem` item children?
I've found only `QQuickItemChangeListener` but this class is from private API.

UPD1:
Implementation of attached property:

```
class MyProp : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int prop ...)
    public:
        explicit MyProp(QObject * object = nullptr) : QObject(object) {
            auto item = qobject_cast<QQuickItem *>(object);
            if(item) {
                for(auto child : _item->childItems()) {
                    QObject * attached = qmlAttachedPropertiesObject<MyProp>(child, true);
                    ... // needs to listen here for adding/removing child items
                }
            }
        }

        static MyProp * qmlAttachedProperties(QObject * object) {
            return new MyProp(object);
        }
}

QML_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(MyProp, QML_HAS_ATTACHED_PROPERTIES)
```

Comment: Are you sure about your design ? Because duplicating properties in all children sounds weird to me. Do you possibly need a different value in each children ? If not, your parent could have the properties and the children just read them instead of the propagation.

Comment: Yes I'm sure about it. For example inside qt code such approach is used in `QQuickAttachedObject` class.

Comment: This sounds like a very bad solution to a problem that can most likely be resolved in a much easier and more efficient way. For example, adding the value as a context property of an object will allow the entire object branch the object is root of to resolve and access it.

Comment: Well if context property value can be created/changed from qml code it can solve the problem.

Comment: It cannot be created but it can be changed. Also if you declare the property in a QML file in the scope of its root object, that property will be resolvable from all objects in that tree via dynamic scoping, unless it gets shadowed by an identically named one of course. Unlike the context property this solution can be implemented without any C++ whatsoever.

Comment: And finally, as long as you give the branch root object a unique `id`, that too can be resolved from within any object of that tree, so even if you don't utilize dynamic scoping, you can easily get a handle on the object of interest and access its properties.

Comment: An alternative could be returning the same attached object for an Item hierarchy. That could work if you don't need to have access to all the QML objects from c++ but only the main one

Answer (score 0):

Using QML you have the `Item` properties [`data`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop), [`children`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#children-prop) and [`resources`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#resources-prop) :

> The children property contains the list of visual children of this
>   item. The resources property contains non-visual resources that you
>   want to reference by name.
>   [...] the default data property will
>   automatically assign child objects to the children and resources
>   properties as appropriate.

When you add some `Item` as a child of your object :
`myItem->setParentItem(parentQQuickItem);`
You can listen to the change in QML code :

```
MyParentItem
{
    onDataChanged:
    {
        // Parse children and modify them
    }
}
```

Or use `onChildrenChanged` for visual items only or `onResourcesChanged`for the non-visual items only.

Comment: Yes, it sounds reasonable, but attached property implemented in c++ code, and I don't know how to implement part of it in QML.

Comment: You could add an invokable function in your C++ class that do the stuff and trigger it on the QML event (or even simpler try to connect a C++ slot to this signal, never tried this though).

Comment: Yes I can call C++ code from qml, but in this case I have to add this code for parent item, then for all its child items, then for all child items of these child item etc. I don't want to do job that computer can do.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this currently, unfortunately. You can vote for and watch this suggestion to be notified of when it's implemented:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-74320